# Please help to identify this shrub

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit

[image][image]
Please help to identify this shrub in Hong Kong: 
- dark green fruit with white spot
- fruits cluster at top of stem
- upright growing of green leaves

The shrub was from Hong Kong MacLehose Country Park Trail in Tuen Mun (somewhere near a reservoir), route 10. The place was of an altitude about 200m (600 feet from sea level) hot and humid. Hong Kong weather is South of the tropic of Cancer which is equal to Hawaii in latitude.

Comment: It would help if you tell us where it grows, and whether it's wild or cultivated.  Some indication of scale would help, too.

Comment: The shrub was from Hong Kong MacLehose Country Park Trail in Tuen Mun (somewhere near a reservoir), route 10.  The place was of an altitude about 200m (600 feet from sea level) hot and humid. Hong Kong weather is South of the tropic of Cancer which is equal to Hawaii in latitude.

Comment: The plant was confirmed as Mussaenda pubescens. Common in Hong Kong but most people recognized the plant by its yellow flower and white leaf (fruit was mostly not seen concurrently).  

My friend used a reversed image search smartphone app to get the suggested plant name in 30 seconds.

Mussaenda is a genus of flowering plants in the Rubiaceae family. They are native to the African and Asian tropics and subtropics.
 ( Mussaenda philippica in Singapore. Mussaenda pubescens in China. Mussaenda erythrophylla in China etc.)

Comment: Sources of reference are such as from:

Hong Kong - http://www.hkwildlife.net/Forum/viewthread.php?action=printable&tid=5497

Taiwan - https://bruce0342.blogspot.com/2014/08/blog-post.html

Comment: @RudyLaw You should post what was confirmed as an answer to this question, instead of a comment.